# Bash sum 5 digits number

Tags: bash, sum

In bash, i need to add (sum) one to a five digit number. The 5 digit number is extracted from a string.

Ex:
To get the 5 digits from the string that resides in a txt file:

```
#!/bin/bash
SUBSTRING_LATEST=$(echo $MYFILE | cut -c15-19)
```

That line returns: 00016

I'm trying to sum 1 to that number and get  the final result like 00017

Tried this, but no luck

```
SUM_FINAL=$((SUBSTRING_LATEST + 1))
```

But that returns 15

I really appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: numbers with leading 0's are treated as octal. octal(17) = integer(15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `base 10` arithmetic otherwise any number starting with a `0` is interpreted as octal number:

```
s='00016'
printf "%05d" $((10#$s + 1))
00017
```

Using octal arithmetic you will get:

```
printf "%05d" $(($s + 1))
00015
```

Comment: I didn't know you could specify base 10 arithmetic like that +1.

Comment: @Jonny `bash` does support a `printf`: `printf "%05d" $SUM_FINAL`

Comment: Thanks I added 0s but leading `0` has no meaning in a number and there might be more/less than 3 leading 0s as well

Comment: Thank u so much anubhava, Jonnny, lurker. All your comments helped me! Now i have what i wanted!